# After trying MS' solutions, File Explorer still does not work with long paths and filenames

Tags: windows, filesystems, windows-11

I have a complex library of files, documents, and media stored in a tree of several directory layers. Windows has always had problems with these folders and files, complaining about their being too long, both in Windows 10 and now Windows 11 (Home edition).

I have used the fixes suggested by Microsoft (see the links below) and still Windows fails to handle my folder structure and files.

Microsoft's docs and instructions I've followed:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry
- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-extend-file-path-characters-maximum-limit/691ea463-2e15-452b-8426-8d372003504f

The error:
[image]

The first thing I tried:
[image]

The second thing I tried:
[image]

The third thing I tried:
[image]

Comment: I added a more applicable duplicate. Essentially File Explorer still has not been updated to support paths longer than 260 characters.